# How to dynamically compute input to pig LOAD command

Tags: apache-pig

Is there a way to dynamically compute the input value to a LOAD statement in pig? Conceptually, I want to do something like this:

```
%declare MYINPUT com.foo.myMethod('2013-04-15');
raw = LOAD '$MYINPUT' ...
```

myMethod() is a UDF that accepts a date as input and returns a (comma-separated) list of directories as a string. That string is then given as the input to the LOAD statement.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound to me like myMethod() needs to be a UDF. Presuming this list of directories doesn't need to be computed in map reduce you could run the function to get the string first, then make it a property you pass to pig. Sample if your driver was in java provided below:

```
String myInput = myMethod("2013-04-15");
PigServer pig = new PigServer(ExecType.MAPREDUCE);
Map<String,String> myProperties = new HashMap<String,String>();
myProperties.put("myInput",myInput);
pig.registerScript("myScriptLocation.pig");
```

and then your script would start with

```
raw = LOAD '$myInput' USING...
```

this is assuming your myInput String is in a glob format PigStorage can read, or you have a different LoadFunc that can handle your comma separated string in mind.

Comment: To extend this, Pig supports Jython, JS (via Rhino) JRuby and Groovy natively. You can easily write the stuff OP needs using those and whoever interfaces with the Pig script in question would never even notice. More info in [the docs](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/cont.html)

Answer (score 0):

[I had a similar issue and opted for a Java LoadFunc implementation instead of a pre-processor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14885333/restricting-loading-of-log-files-in-pig-latin-based-on-interested-date-range-as). Using a custom LoadFunc means the script can still be run by analysts using the stock pig executable, and doesn't require another dependency.